# Query from database multiple rows, but get them in gridview on only one row

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I have 4 tables

Equipments:
Laptop : ID - PK, laptop_model, laptop_series, laptop_date_acq, status;

Display : ID - PK, display_model, display_series, display_date_acq, status;

Phone : ID - PK, phone_model, phone_series, phone_date_acq, status;

UserEquipmentMapping: ID - PK, laptop_id ( FK TO id from table laptop), display_id(FK to id from table display), phone_id(FK to id from table Phone), start_date, end_date.

For each user, i am mapping an unique equipment with start_date and end_date, so for now in userequipmentmapping/index i am getting for one user 4 rows like this :

USER_X - Display_model - NULL - NULL - START_DATE - END_DATE;

USER_X - Display_model - NULL - NULL - START_DATE - NULL;

USER_X - NULL -    Phone Model - NULL - START_DATE - NULL;

USER_X - NULL - NULL - Laptop Model - START_DATE - NULL;

i want in my grid_view to get on one single row an user with the equipments without end_date.

USER_X - DISPLAY_MODEL - PHONE_MODEL - LAPTOP_MODEL ( The ones without end_date, because the ones with end_date are not available anymore) and in view for each user to see all the equipments assigned, with or without end_date.

Any guidance is a lot of help, being a beginner in yii2. Thank you in advance !

Here is the code:

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\UserEquipmentMapping;
use app\models\UserequipmentmappingSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use app\models\User;
use app\models\Laptop;
use app\models\Phone;
use app\models\Display;
/**
 * UserequipmentmappingController implements the CRUD actions for UserEquipmentMapping model.
 */
class UserequipmentmappingController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all UserEquipmentMapping models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $usermodel = new UserEquipmentMapping();
        
        $userquery = $usermodel->getUsers();
        
        $displaymodel = new UserEquipmentMapping();
        $displayquery = $displaymodel->getDisplays();
        
        $phonemodel = new UserEquipmentMapping();
        $phonequery = $phonemodel->getPhones();
        
        $laptopmodel = new UserEquipmentMapping();
        $laptopquery = $laptopmodel->getLaptops();
        #foreach($query as $q)
    #       print_r($q);
#       
#       die;
        
        $searchModel = new UserequipmentmappingSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
                
        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'userquery' => $userquery,
            'displayquery' => $displayquery,
            'laptopquery'=> $laptopquery,
            'phonequery'=> $phonequery,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single UserEquipmentMapping model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new UserEquipmentMapping model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new UserEquipmentMapping();
        
        $usermodel = User::find()->all();
        $laptopmodel = Laptop::find()->all();
        $phonemodel = Phone::find()->all();
        $displaymodel = Display::find()->all();
        
        
        
        #die;
        #print_r(Yii::$app->request->post()); die;
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
            //code
            #foreach($laptopmodel as $m){
            #print_r($m->status );
            #print_r($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()));
            #print_r($model);
            #print_r($model->laptop_id);
            #print_r($laptopmodel);
            #die;
            if($model->laptop_id)
            {
                $laptop = Laptop::findOne($model->laptop_id);
                $laptop->status = Laptop::STATUS_ASSIGNED;
                $laptop->save();
            }
            if($model->display_id)
            {
                $display = Display::findOne($model->display_id);
                $display->status = Display::STATUS_ASSIGNED;
                $display->save();
            }
            if($model->phone_id)
            {
                $phone = Phone::findOne($model->phone_id);
                $phone->status = Phone::STATUS_ASSIGNED;
                $phone->save();
            }
            $model->save();
            
            return $this->redirect(['index', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            'usermodel' => $usermodel,
            'laptopmodel' => $laptopmodel,
            'phonemodel' => $phonemodel,
            'displaymodel' => $displaymodel,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing UserEquipmentMapping model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        $usermodel = User::find()->all();
        $laptopmodel = Laptop::find()->all();
        $phonemodel = Phone::find()->all();
        $displaymodel = Display::find()->all();
        
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }

        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
            'usermodel' => $usermodel,
            'laptopmodel' => $laptopmodel,
            'phonemodel' => $phonemodel,
            'displaymodel' => $displaymodel,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing UserEquipmentMapping model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the UserEquipmentMapping model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return UserEquipmentMapping the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = UserEquipmentMapping::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        }

        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
```

Model :

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use app\models\User;
use app\models\UserQuery;
use yii\db\ActiveQuery;
/**
 * This is the model class for table "user_equipment_mapping".
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property int $user_id
 * @property int|null $laptop_id
 * @property int|null $phone_id
 * @property int|null $display_id
 * @property string|null $start_date
 * @property string|null $stop_date
 *
 * @property Display $display
 * @property Laptop $laptop
 * @property Phone $phone
 * @property User $user
 */
class UserEquipmentMapping extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'user_equipment_mapping';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['user_id'], 'required'],
            [['user_id', 'laptop_id', 'phone_id', 'display_id'], 'integer'],
            [['start_date', 'stop_date'], 'safe'],
            [['display_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Display::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['display_id' => 'id']],
            [['laptop_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Laptop::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['laptop_id' => 'id']],
            [['phone_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Phone::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['phone_id' => 'id']],
            [['user_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => User::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['user_id' => 'id']],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'user_id' => 'User ID',
            'laptop_id' => 'Laptop ID',
            'phone_id' => 'Phone ID',
            'display_id' => 'Display ID',
            'start_date' => 'Start Date',
            'stop_date' => 'Stop Date',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Gets query for [[Display]].
     *
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery|DisplayQuery
     */
    public function getDisplay()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Display::className(), ['id' => 'display_id']);
    }

    /**
     * Gets query for [[Laptop]].
     *
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery|LaptopQuery
     */
    public function getLaptop()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Laptop::className(), ['id' => 'laptop_id']);
    }

    /**
     * Gets query for [[Phone]].
     *
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery|PhoneQuery
     */
    public function getPhone()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Phone::className(), ['id' => 'phone_id']);
    }

    /**
     * Gets query for [[User]].
     *
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery|UserQuery
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
    }
    
    
    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::className(),['user_id', 'id']);
    }

    public function getLaptops()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Laptop::className(),['laptop_id', 'id']);
    }
    
    public function getDisplays()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Display::className(),['dislpay_id', 'id']);
    }
    
    public function getPhones()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Phone::className(),['phone_id', 'id']);
    }
    
    
    
    
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @return UserEquipmentMappingQuery the active query used by this AR class.
     */
    public static function find()
    {
        return new UserEquipmentMappingQuery(get_called_class());
    }
}
```

Index:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel app\models\UserequipmentmappingSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'User Equipment Mappings';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="user-equipment-mapping-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a('Create User Equipment Mapping', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </p>

    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>
    
    
    
    
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'formatter' => [
            'class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter',
            'nullDisplay' => '-',],
        'columns' => [
            #['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            #'id',
            #'user.username',
            ['attribute' => 'user',
                'label' => 'Username',
                'value' => 'user.username'
                #},
            ],
            #'laptop.laptop_model',
            ['attribute' => 'laptop',
                'label' => 'Laptop Series',
                'value' => 'laptop.laptop_series'
                #},
            ],
            
            #'laptop_id',
            #'phone.phone_model',
            ['attribute' => 'phone',
                'label' => 'Phone Series',
                'value' => 'phone.phone_series'
                #},
            ],
            #'phone_id',
            #'display.display_model',
            ['attribute' => 'display',
                'label' => 'Display Series',
                'value' => 'display.display_series'
                #},
            ],
            #'display_id',
            'start_date',
            'stop_date',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn', 'header' => "Actions"],
        ],
    ]); ?>


</div>
```

Form:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use app\models\User;
use kartik\date\DatePicker;
use yii\web\View;
use yii\web\JqueryAsset;
use app\models\Laptop;
use app\models\Display;
use app\models\Phone;

$userData=ArrayHelper::map($usermodel, 'id','username');
$laptopData=ArrayHelper::map($laptopmodel,'id','laptop_series');
$phoneData=ArrayHelper::map($phonemodel,'id','phone_series');
$displayData=ArrayHelper::map($displaymodel,'id','display_series');

$availablelaptopData = ArrayHelper::map(Laptop::find()->where(['status' => 'Available'])->all(), 'id', 'laptop_series');
$availablephoneData = ArrayHelper::map(Phone::find()->where(['status' => 'Available'])->all(), 'id', 'phone_series');
$availabledisplayData = ArrayHelper::map(Display::find()->where(['status' => 'Available'])->all(), 'id', 'display_series');

?>
        
<div class="user-equipment-mapping-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
        
    
        
    <?=$form->field($model, 'user_id')->dropDownList($userData, ['prompt'=>'Select...']);?>
    
    <?=$form->field($model, 'laptop_id')->dropDownList($availablelaptopData, ['prompt'=>'Select...']);?>    

    <?=$form->field($model, 'phone_id')->dropDownList($availablephoneData, ['prompt'=>'Select...']);?>

    <?=$form->field($model, 'display_id')->dropDownList($availabledisplayData, ['prompt'=>'Select...']);?>

    

    <?=$form->field($model, 'start_date')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
        'language' => 'en',
        'value' => date('yyyy/mm/dd', strtotime('+7 days')),
        'readonly' => true,
        #'disabled' => true,
        #'size' => 'lg',
        #'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_COMPONENT_APPEND,
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Selectati data'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            #'orientation' => 'top right',
            'format' => 'yyyy/mm/dd',
            'todayHighlight' => true,
            'todayBtn' => true,
            'autoclose'=>true,
        ]
    ]);?>

    <?=$form->field($model, 'stop_date')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
        'language' => 'en',
        'value' => date('yyyy/mm/dd', strtotime('+7 days')),
        'readonly' => true,
        #'disabled' => true,
        #'size' => 'lg',
        #'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_COMPONENT_APPEND,
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Selectati data'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            #'orientation' => 'top right',
            'format' => 'yyyy/mm/dd',
            'todayHighlight' => true,
            'todayBtn' => true,
            'autoclose'=>true,
        ]
    ]);?>





    
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: This is a Pivot table there is a extension which maybe help (I haven't used it so far) https://github.com/d3yii2/d3data 
I had always created a single array myself and used it as input for an ArrayDataProvider for the Gridview